# What did I hit drilling into my wall?

Tags: walls, studs

I am trying to drill for some curtains.

I was assuming that my walls were plaster, because my stud finder was useless and the magnet was not sticking to anything.

I am using titanium (coated?) drill bits 3/32 bit.

This is about 6 inches to the side and above the edge of a window. the window frame is steel (my magnet sticks) and extends about 2 inches or so from the edge of the window.

There is an outlet directly under the window, but there is the light switch for the living room lights about 1 foot from the left side of the edge of the window.

I got about a quarter inch in before I hit something hard that my drill was not cutting through.

I gave it a half second of drilling on low speed to see if I would see any metal filings, but I did not see any.

However when I scratch a smaller bit against the end of the hole, it does *feel* like metal.

Additionally the magnet is not sticking to the location that I was drilling. So I can't imagine that would be a plate on a stud, since I have only heard of using steel for such a thing.

Also the hard surface seems pretty flat from what I can tell, I cant imagine it would be conduit (with a circular cross section).

Finally, the same thing happened on the other side of the window at the same height, again 6 inches to the right of the window.

This is the outer wall of my apartment, facing into the apartment complex.

Any idea what I am hitting? It cant be brick or steel. I will ask my landlord but they might just ignore me because landlord.

Comment: edit: the reason was because my drill was going the wrong way. There is no metal object.

Comment: i am leaving this up for people to make fun of me

Comment: thanks for being a good sport,.

Comment: You are not alone, although most would not say anything.  On a commercial construction project, one of my crew spent most of the afternoon fighting to drill 1/4" holes in metal studs.  After complaining, one of the other guys teased, asking if the drill was going the right direction, to which the response was: "What do you mean?  Drilling is drilling!"

Comment: If you intend to leave this up for future searchers, could you please put the solution in the answer space & mark it as accepted. The 'reddit style' of putting solved in the title & the answer at the end of the question does not work for Stack Exchange.

Comment: beautiful, well done

Answer (score 5):

The reason this happened was because my drill was turning the wrong way. There is no metal object.

Comment: Thankfully you didn't keep going and work hardened it too much, or even set your wall on fire.